# Where can I find the current installed version of the App Engine Maven plugin in my system?

Tags: java, macos, maven, google-cloud-platform

The current (of this writing) version is 2.0.0 (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin)

I have updated my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</plugin>
```

I am getting this Build error on `mvn appengine:help -Ddetail`

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.027 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-28T15:38:52-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and 
    in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from 
    the repositories [local (/Users/private/.m2/repository), 
    central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
```

Where can I find the plugin install location on my MacOS, or how can I determine the version installed?

Comment: Based on the website the 2.0.0 is not yet available only [2.0.0-rc5](https://search.maven.org/search?q=appengine-maven-plugin)

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for that clarification. I updated `<version>1.3.2</version>`. Build now successful. The USER_GUIDE.md for this plugin (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/blob/master/USER_GUIDE.md#applying-the-plugin) just mentioned `<version>VERSION</version>. Was mislead by thinking it was 2.0.0. Anyway to determine version installed? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As per @khmarbaise tip, modified `<version>2.0.0</version>` to 1.3.2. Build now successful.

Comment: Found this link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.tools/appengine-maven-plugin. Lists App Engine Maven Plugin current versions.